# How to add social sharing buttons in django blog

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, django

am using the django_social_share module and i cant figure out how to pass the sharing url for a particular blog post on social media 
here is the post_detail.html

```html
<article>
  <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
<img src="{{post.thumb.url}}" alt="" />
</div>
  <div class="post-content">
<h2>{{post.title}}</h2>
<div>
{{post.created}}  Author {{post.user}}
<hr/>
<p>{{post.body}}</p>
<hr>
<div id="subheader" class="blog">
  <div class="subheader-text">
    <h1>Did you like this Post ?</h1>
    <h4>Consider sharing Most readers like to share our Posts </h4>
  <a href="#" rel="shared-popover" data-popover-content="#shared-btn-Popover" title="Share" data-placement="bottom" class="mtr-btn button-circle button-fab ripple"><i class="fa fa-share-alt"></i></a>
<div id="shared-btn-Popover" class="hide">
  <ul class="blog-share-buttons">
    <li><a href="{% post_to_twitter object.title %}" title="Twitter"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="{% post_to_facebook object.title %}" title="Facebook"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="#" title="Linkedin"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
</article>
</div>
```

help out please all the setting are okay

Comment: Which url you want to pass?

Comment: The URL containing the particular post I mean the post_list function renders the blog.html which contains the list of posts and once a post is clicked displays the post detail from post_detail function so trying to share this post is the problem as you can see in the post_detail.html

Answer (score 0):

I think you just can you `"{% post_to_twitter post.get_absolte_url %}"`

If you didn't make yet, you can make it in your model

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('post:detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

(Of course you have to change your own reverse())

Answer (score 0):

I know it's late but you can do it like this:

```
{% post_to_facebook  object_or_url "this is where you insert your i tag with icon" %}
```

Use the double quotes as I did in the example.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

```
{% load social_share %}

{% post_to_facebook object_or_url "Post to Facebook!" %}
```

you must enter the keyword "`object_or_url`" plain...it will use the get_absolute_url

thats what i could understand from the django-social-share info

what i dont know its how to put icons instead. It says there s a parameter link_class but dont explain how to use it